# the xampp apache server also support in Java EE

Tags: php, jakarta-ee

I am using **xampp server**. Does it support Jsp and Java servlets? If not, is there any server that supports both '**php and Java EE**' and to how to use it

Answer (score 3):

Use Apache Tomcat 7.0, it will support both PHP and Java EE.

Comment: plz sent to the url in Apache tomcat

Answer (score 2):

As stated in official xampp web page it supports:
with the release of the new version of XAMPP 1.8.0,

- Apache 2.4.2
- MySQL 5.5.25a
- PHP 5.4.4 phpMyAdmin 3.5.2
- FileZilla FTP  Server 0.9.41
- **Tomcat 7.0.28 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector)**
- Strawberry Perl 5.16.0.1 Portable
- XAMPP Control Panel 3.0.12 (from
  hackattack142)

it seems with the tomcat server you can deploy your application if java configurations ([Java SE JDK 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)) are done properly. In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUV_jPdq7fc) (Integrating Tomcat with Apache Using XAMPP Part 1) it tells how to do it but basically you can put your jsp file to `/xampp/tomcat/webapps` folder.

In my opinion starting using netbeans IDE and selecting the XAMPP server as a default server you can deploy your javaEE applications easily, a good start is [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html).

For PHP tomcat supports and also XAMMP has very is easy configuration for PHP projects, you can follow the details from this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ae55c6Ds3-g).